# Scope of CloudWatch event rule for AWS Health

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

I want to grab all the events for AWS Health with
[CloudWatch event rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Gov.png) that targets SNS topic.

Personal Health Dashboard (AWS Health) operates on global scope but CloudWatch event rule is set on particular region eg. eu-central-1.

The question here is: should I expect to retrieve all the events for all the regions from AWS Health or the events will be scoped to the region that CloudWatch event rule resides on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/cloudwatch-events-health.html)

> Events that appear in the Personal Health Dashboard are Region-specific. For example, if AWS Health sends an event that affects a resource (such as an Amazon EC2 instance) in the US East (Ohio) Region, you must configure CloudWatch Events in the same Region to get notified of that event.